# Google-Apps-Script/Google-Drive cors issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Apps Script in Google Drive.  Although the script was created in Drive, it has a URL that looks like:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/blah-blah-blah

As a result, attempts to stuff the output from the script into a web page hosted on Google Drive fail as an attempt to access a cross-origin resource.  Any way I can get around this problem?  Thanks for any input.

```
    ... doug
```

Comment: Google removed web page hosting from Google Drive, so this can't be reproduced anymore.

Answer (score 1):

you could publish the gas as anonymous content script and use ajax to get the data (redirects enabled) and use regular client+side js to display it on your googledrive html page.
Maybe its not working because you havent published as anonymous? 
Ive done ajax to a gas content script from a googledrive.com hosted page and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm reading the 2 sentences of your answer as alternatives. So, if I'm reading your answer correctly, I could go with just the 2nd alternative (2nd sentence) which would be to publish the gas as an anonymous content script, use ajax to get the data, and regular client+side js to display it on the google drive html page. I don't see how that's any different from what I am doing. I think that I must be mis-understanding your answer. Am I understanding it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood as iframing it. ive updated the answer to only consider old case #2